# Stripe CLI trigger payment intent with specific id

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe in my application and I use the payment intent id also as the identifier to store my customer order details. I wrote a webhook endpoint in order to change customer order status and I would like to test locally first.

How can I trigger payment_intent.succeeded event with a specific payment_intent id so that I can find my customer order from the database?

Comment: I opened an issue with stripe-cli. I am trying to do the same thing as OP. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/753

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to trigger it with a specific Payment Intent like that; what you'll want to do instead is use the CLI's forwarding, but go through your flow to actually create a test payment.  That will result in a `payment_intent.succeeded` event for an expected/known Payment Intent.

Comment: I want to do this but for bank transfers, where I would guess the successful payment intent is only generated once a transfer to stripe is made.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem whereby I wanted to test a failed subscription payment. Looking into the Stripe CLI fixtures, I took the default [json](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/master/triggers/invoice.payment_failed.json) they use and created the following script.

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { exec } = require('child_process')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const args = process.argv.slice(2)

if (args[0] !== '-customer') {
  console.log('-customer argument missing')
  process.exit(22)
}

if (args[1] === undefined) {
  console.log('customer id required')
  process.exit(22)
}

const failedInvoiceJson = {
  _meta: {
    template_version: 0
  },
  fixtures: [
    {
      name: 'invoiceitem',
      path: '/v1/invoiceitems',
      method: 'post',
      params: {
        amount: 2000,
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: `${args[1]}`,
        description: '(created by Stripe CLI)'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'invoice',
      path: '/v1/invoices',
      method: 'post',
      params: {
        customer: `${args[1]}`,
        description: '(created by Stripe CLI)'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'invoice_pay',
      path: '/v1/invoices/${invoice:id}/pay',
      method: 'post'
    }
  ]
}

fs.writeFileSync(
  path.join(process.cwd(), './test/failedInvoice.json'),
  JSON.stringify(failedInvoiceJson)
)

exec('stripe fixtures test/failedInvoice.json', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)

  fs.unlinkSync(path.join(process.cwd(), './test/failedInvoice.json'))

  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`)
    return
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    return
  }
})
```

With this script I'm able to run the command `node test/failedInvoice.ts -customer xxx` where `xxx` is the ID of an existing stripe user in my database.

Answer (score 1):

When the payment is succeeded on the payment page, write an UPDATE query to change the status of the order.

To do this, you need to store the order_id while creating the Payment Intent. Use **metadata** field.

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'metadata' => [
        'order_id' => '6735',
    ],
]);
```

Retrieve the order_id from the Payment Intent when the payment is succeeded to update the status of the order.

Answer (score 0):

Take a template from [the repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/master/triggers/invoice.payment_succeeded.json) and change a variable like `${invoice:id}` to use an environment variable, i.e. `${.env:INVOICE_ID}`. Then, you can call `INVOICE_ID=10 stripe fixtures yourfile.json`.